# Swiping gestures

Tags: android

I'd like to implement a small feature on my application that allows the user to swipe left and swipe right on a fixed part of the screen. A swipe left would call a certain method and a swipe right would call a different method. I've seen swipe examples where the activity changes upon swiping left or right, but I only want to call methods, and have it only available on a small part of the screen.

Is this possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction to a library or good tutorial?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Dictionary says Swipe: "an act or instance of moving one's finger across a touchscreen to activate a function."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SimpleOnGestureListener API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html). You sure can handle swipes and call methods from them. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-swipe-gesture-implementation/). When you implement the SimpleGestureActivity in your activity, call your methods from the appropriate cases in the switch statement.